# How to print specific values to CLI upon invocation of `pulumi up`?

Tags: c#, pulumi

When I invoke `pulumi up`, I want it to print as part its output - the public IP of the `Pulumi.Aws.Ec2.Instance` (e.g. `Public IP: 1.2.3.4`).

I have this code:

```
var server = new Instance("auto_mc_server", new InstanceArgs {
    InstanceType = "t2.micro",
    // ... more stuff ...
});
```

I see many questions asking about `Output`s, so I tried for instance:

1. `Output.Format($"Public IP: {server.PublicIp}");`
2. `Output.Create("public_ip").Apply(s => $"Public IP: {server.PublicIp}");`

... and other variations ...

But nothing gets printed upon `pulumi up`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a value in the C# SDK

```
return new Dictionary<string, object?>
{
   ["publicIp"] = server.PublicIp
};
```

Comment: Right, together with another way I found to do that: `Server.PublicIp.Apply(publicIp => { Console.WriteLine($"Public IP: {publicIp}"); return publicIp; });`. Your answer seems to be the "official" way to expose outputs I suppose (allowing it to compare changes across deployments, apparently), while this way is "just" a simple text-outputting